# Smack 4.4.2 establish secure connection by certificates

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have 3 certificates root.crt, network.crt components.crt must be sent with the request to establish a connection. In Smack 4.1.3 i use this-

````
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration = 
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setServiceName("hostname")
                    .setHost("hostname")
                    .setCompressionEnabled(false)
                    .setPort(5222)
                    .setResource("Something")
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                    .setUsernameAndPassword("somename","password")
                    .setCustomSSLContext(sslContext).build();
            AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
            connection.connect();
            connection.login();

It worked perfectly. Now I am using Smack 4.4.2 how do I make a connection? I am using this code below-             


         ```XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = null;
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder;
            try {
                builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setServiceName(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(Important.getXmppHost()))
                        .setHost(Important.getXmppHost())
                       // .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                        .setPort(Integer.parseInt(Important.getXmppPort()))
                        .setUsernameAndPassword(getLoginInfo("phone_no"), getLoginInfo("sec"))
                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                        .setResource(Important.getXmppResource())
                        .setCompressionEnabled(false);
                KeyStore keyStore = configKeyStore(builder);
                configSSLContext(builder, keyStore);
                config = builder.build();

            } catch (XmppStringprepException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
````

```
private KeyStore configKeyStore(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder) throws KeyStoreException {
    KeyStore keyStore;

    builder.setKeystorePath(null);
    builder.setKeystoreType("AndroidCAStore");
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
    return keyStore;
}

private void configSSLContext(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder, KeyStore keyStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    builder.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
}
```

As the SetCustomSSLContext is deprecated, The Server is giving me this-
`error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

How do connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to solve this situation.
used

```
.setCustomX509TrustManager(trustfactory)
```

solved my problem.